# How to initialize n number of different list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create n number of lists like

```
a_1 = [some data]
a_2 = [some data]
a_3 = [some data]
.          .
.          .
.          .
.          .
.          .
a_n = [some data]
```

I thought for looping would help

```
for i in range(10):
    a_i = []
    print(a_i)
```

My approach is fully wrong because the output I was expecting should be like

```
a_1 = [some data]
a_2 = [some data]
a_3 = [some data]
.          .
.          .
.          .
.          .
.          .
a_n = [some data]
```

instead of

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your data stored or how you are getting it? Please mentioned that as well.

Comment: ignore the data part just help me with n number of empty list , however the list should be initialized like the way I have mentioned @JayeshDhandha

Comment: If you will not apply any data than what approach you have done is fine! It will be empty list.

Comment: but the whole output is now under a_i, the output I want is a_1 =[] , a_2 =[], ....a_n = [] @JayeshDhandha

Comment: Why don't you use list of lists?

Comment: that approach won't help me, the problem I am solving is I am getting n number of different inputs and I have to save it in n number of different lists with different initialization @JayeshDhandha

Comment: yes almost duplicate but I got the idea thank you @JayeshDhandha

Comment: Please paste your answer so that others can get benefit of it. If it's different than the one which told. Thanks!

Comment: With your approach, in each loop `a_i` is overwritten each time. It does not take the values a_1, a_2 etc, it just reinitialize the list a_i over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also:

```
for i in range(5):
    exec('a_%d = []'%i)
```

Don't know if it has (dis)advantages over the `globals` method suggested in one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Could try:

```
list_of_lists = []
for i in range(10):
    a_i = [] # put some data on the list
    list_of_lists.append(a_i)
print(lists_of_lists)
```